# how to properly setup python counter? and what is wrong with current logic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

```
def some_func():
  success_count = 0
  fail_count = 0
  try:
    do_this_thing()
    success_count += 1
    fail_count = 0
    print(f"success count is {success_count}.")

  except this_error:
    fail_count += 1
    success_count = 0
    print(f"retrying. retried {fail_count} times.")
```

this is the structure of my code. everything else works fine except the success_count and the fail_count.
id expect success_count be reset everytime the try function is ran, and the success_count be reset when we reach an exception, output be like shown below.

```
success count is 1.
success count is 2.
success count is 3.
retrying. retried 1 times.
retrying. retried 2 times.
success count is 1.
success count is 2.
```

but instead i got:

```
success count is 1.
success count is 2.
success count is 3.
retrying. retried 1 times.
retrying. retried 2 times.
success count is 4.
success count is 5.
```

what is wrong with the current logic? why is success_count not being reset.

EDIT:
this following code is for recreating the problem, and somehow the testing code works perfectly. yet my real code, using the same structure doesnt. now im more baffled.

```
import time
import random
def randomly_raise_except_func():
  k = random.randint(1,2)
  if k == 1:
    pass
  if k == 2:
    raise ValueError("this is a error to recreate the problem")

def some_func():
  success_count = 0
  fail_count = 0
  while True:
    try:
        randomly_raise_except_func()
        success_count += 1
        fail_count = 0
        print(f"success count is {success_count}.")
        time.sleep(2)
    except ValueError:
        fail_count += 1
        success_count = 0
        
        print(f"retrying. retried {fail_count} times.")
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
      
some_func()
```

Comment: you are printing`{success_counter}` instead of `{success_count}`. is that a typo?

Comment: yes that is. @meowulf, i edited it to the right thing.

Comment: it appears that you are using loop, but where? is it outside the `some_func()` function or inside the `some_func()` function?

Comment: If you can re-write the code as a minimally reproducible bit of code that we could copy into our own environment to run and debug it would make it much easier to answer. My first guess is that the problem lies outside the code you provided.

Comment: @meowulf If the loop is external to `some_func`, the counters would be reset to 0 each time the function is called, so we'd never see values larger than 1.

Comment: The output you showed can't be coming fromthe code you posted.

Comment: i added a block of code to recreate the system. but it works perfectly fine. @DavidParks

Comment: i added codes that reproduces the output @Barmar

Comment: There's obviously something different in the structure of the real code than the snippet you posted. We can't help you if you can't post code with the problem.

Comment: My guess is a typo, and you're resetting the wrong variable in the exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line :

```py
random.seed(22)  # set a seed, so that results are reproducible
```

before

```py
some_func()
```

so I got the output :

```
success count is 1.
success count is 2.
success count is 3.
retrying. retried 1 times.
success count is 1.
success count is 2.
retrying. retried 1 times.
success count is 1.
success count is 2.
...
```

which looks fine to me : the success counter is reset to 0 each time an exception occurs. Your code seems to do what you ask. If not, please provide clarification.